# How to parse Hex with String, Float

Tags: swift

I have binary files which containing names of place and coordinates ( latitude, longitude ), whenever I parse it to `String` using encoding `.ascii` it won't parse it well. I assume that parsing from `Float` values (coordinates) failing.

Reading `InputStream`

```
extension Data {
    init(reading input: InputStream) {
        self.init()
        input.open()

        let bufferSize = 1024
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
        while input.hasBytesAvailable {
            let read = input.read(buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
            self.append(buffer, count: read)
        }
        buffer.deallocate()

        input.close()
    }
}
```

[File to parse](https://uploadfiles.io/43gqu)

```
let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MN", ofType: "dat")
let data = Data.init(reading: InputStream(fileAtPath: filepath)!)
let parsedData = String.init(data: data, encoding: .ascii)
```

[image: Parsing result]

Any ideas how could I parse it in correct way ?

For example Java `ObjectInputStream` have methods called:

```
inputStreamObj.readUTF()
inputStreamObj.readFloat()
```

**Java**

[image]

Comment: In `Java` you are parsing the String as UTF encoded, so why are you treating it as an ASCII String in Swift? Use `let parsedData = String.init(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: Java encodes `float` as 4 bytes in Big Endian order, if I remember correctly. If you want to read that in Swift, you will have to read that 4 bytes and use the correct `float.init` initializer. `.readUTF` uses the first 2 bytes as a big endian length of the string. Not a good data format to be shared across different apps.

Comment: @DávidPásztor using `.utf8` going to produce `nil`

Comment: @yerpy If this is encoded from Java, the first 2 bytes of the string are length and you have to read them separately and then read only the given length of bytes.

Comment: It doesn't look like something which can be read directly as `String`

Comment: By the way, you really don't need `InputStream` in Swift. Don't translate Java library to Swift. `Data` can be created from a file URL directly.

Comment: @Sulthan The result is the same, can't produce correct data

Comment: @yerpy Please, show us how the data has been encoded.

Comment: @Sulthan the same as from screen above using 'InputStream'

Comment: @yerpy You are not showing how you create (encode) the data. The data file linked in your question is empty.

Comment: @Sulthan I've replaced the links, I had to zip it first, otherwise it did not upload anything.

Comment: Can you show us the code (maybe in Java) which created the `MN.dat`? Or you can show us a code in any language which can parse it.

Comment: please tell me how to export  MN.dat file if open your file in any editor
content wrong

Comment: @OOPer Here is a snipped screen with code from repo, I can't give u more. I think there is nothing more neccessery for parsing it in Java

Comment: That may not be sufficient, but can be a good start point to try.

Comment: As the Java code is using `ObjectInputStream`, we may need to read the spec [Object Serialization Stream Protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html). According to the spec, the first 9 bytes represents STREAM_MAGIC, STREAM_VERSION, TC_BLOCKDATALONG(0x00000400). Seems the actual data is split into chunks of size 0x0400, and all chunks needs to concatenated before interpreting the contents, seems to be an awful format for non-Java platforms.

Comment: @OOPer Oh god, maybe add your own answer. I didn't think of that and never realized that they could be using `ObjectInputStream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, you need to read the spec [Object Serialization Stream Protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html).

So, first 4 bytes represents STREAM_MAGIC, STREAM_VERSION, expected to be always the same value. And 5 byte sequence 0x7A 0xhh 0xhh 0xhh 0xhh represents TC_BLOCKDATALONG(0xhhhhhhhh).

And all blocks needs to be concatenated before parsing strings and floats.

So, preparing the `DataReader`:

(Nearly the same as Sulthan's, but this treats Modified UTF-8 correctly.)

```
struct DataReader {
    enum DataReaderError: Error {
        case invalidFirstByte(byte: UInt16, offset: Int)
        case invalidFollowingByte
        case missingFollowingByte
        case insufficientData
    }
    var data: Data
    var currentPosition: Int

    init(data: Data) {
        self.data = data
        self.currentPosition = 0
    }

    mutating func skipBytes(_ n: Int) {
        currentPosition += n
    }

    private mutating func readBigEndian<T: FixedWidthInteger>() throws -> T {
        guard currentPosition + MemoryLayout<T>.size <= data.count else {
            throw DataReaderError.insufficientData
        }
        var fixedWithInteger: T = 0
        let range: Range<Int> = currentPosition ..< currentPosition + MemoryLayout<T>.size
        withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &fixedWithInteger) {ptrT in
            let uint8Ptr = ptrT.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
            data.copyBytes(to: uint8Ptr, from: range)
        }
        currentPosition += MemoryLayout<T>.size
        return fixedWithInteger.bigEndian
    }

    mutating func readFloat() throws -> Float {
        let floatBits: UInt32 = try readBigEndian()
        return Float(bitPattern: floatBits)
    }

    mutating func readUnsignedShort() throws -> Int {
        let ushortValue: UInt16 = try readBigEndian()
        return Int(ushortValue)
    }

    mutating func readInt() throws -> Int {
        let intValue: Int32 = try readBigEndian()
        return Int(intValue)
    }

    mutating func readUnsignedByte() throws -> Int {
        guard currentPosition < data.count else {
            throw DataReaderError.insufficientData
        }
        let byte = data[currentPosition]
        currentPosition += 1
        return Int(byte)
    }

    mutating func readBytes(_ n: Int) throws -> Data {
        guard currentPosition + n <= data.count else {
            throw DataReaderError.insufficientData
        }
        let subdata = data[currentPosition ..< currentPosition+n]
        currentPosition += n
        return subdata
    }

    mutating func readUTF() throws -> String {
        //Get byte size of the string
        let count = try readUnsignedShort()
        //Decoding Modified UTF-8
        var utf16: [UInt16] = []
        var offset = 0
        while offset < count {
            let firstByte = UInt16(data[currentPosition + offset])
            if firstByte & 0b1_0000000 == 0b0_0000000 {
                utf16.append(firstByte)
                offset += 1
            } else if firstByte & 0b111_00000 == 0b110_00000 {
                guard offset + 1 < count else {throw DataReaderError.missingFollowingByte}
                let secondByte = UInt16(data[currentPosition + offset + 1])
                guard secondByte & 0b11_000000 == 0b10_000000 else {throw DataReaderError.invalidFollowingByte}
                let codeUnit = ((firstByte & 0b000_11111) << 6) | (secondByte & 0b00_111111)
                utf16.append(codeUnit)
                offset += 2
            } else if firstByte & 0b1111_0000 == 0b1110_0000 {
                guard offset + 2 < count else {throw DataReaderError.missingFollowingByte}
                let secondByte = UInt16(data[currentPosition + offset + 1])
                guard secondByte & 0b11_000000 == 0b10_000000 else {throw DataReaderError.invalidFollowingByte}
                let thirdByte = UInt16(data[currentPosition + offset + 2])
                guard thirdByte & 0b11_000000 == 0b10_000000 else {throw DataReaderError.invalidFollowingByte}
                let codeUnit = ((firstByte & 0b0000_1111) << 12) | ((secondByte & 0b00_111111) << 6) | (thirdByte & 0b00_111111)
                utf16.append(codeUnit)
                offset += 3
            } else {
                throw DataReaderError.invalidFirstByte(byte: firstByte, offset: currentPosition+offset)
            }
        }
        currentPosition += offset
        return String(utf16CodeUnits: &utf16, count: utf16.count)

    }

    var isAtEnd: Bool {
        return currentPosition == data.count
    }
}
```

We can parse your `MN.dat` as follows:

```
let mnUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MN", withExtension: "dat")!
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: mnUrl)
    var reader = DataReader(data: data)
    reader.skipBytes(4)

    //First collect all blocks
    var blockData = Data()
    while !reader.isAtEnd {
        let contentType = try reader.readUnsignedByte()
        if contentType == 0x7A {//TC_BLOCKDATALONG
            let size = try reader.readInt()
            let block = try reader.readBytes(size)
            blockData.append(block)
        } else if contentType == 0x77 {//TC_BLOCKDATA
            let size = try reader.readUnsignedByte()
            let block = try reader.readBytes(size)
            blockData.append(block)
        } else {
            print("Unsupported content type")
            break
        }
    }
    //Then read the contents of blockData
    var blockReader = DataReader(data: blockData)
    while !blockReader.isAtEnd {
        let string = try blockReader.readUTF()
        print(string)
        let float1 = try blockReader.readFloat()
        print(float1)
        let float2 = try blockReader.readFloat()
        print(float2)
        //Use string, float1, float2 as you like
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Output:

```
Albert Lea
43.648
-93.3683
Albertville
45.2377
-93.6544
Alexandria
45.8852
-95.3775
(... no errors...)
Woodbury
44.9239
-92.9594
Worthington
43.62
-95.5964
Wyoming
45.3364
-92.9972
Zimmerman
45.4433
-93.59
```

---

You may need to modify the code above if your binary data may contain other content types.

Comment: You don't need to handle modified utf-8 by yourself. I am pretty sure it would get parsed correctly.

Comment: In most case including the case of the OP's `MN.dat`, you are right. But the difference between UTF-8 and Modified UTF-8 can be found for NUL character (U+0000) and non-BMP characters (U+10000...U+10FFFF). As far as I tested, `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` does not work for NUL neither for non-BMP characters.

Comment: Thanks for an effort ! I am going to deeply analize it.

Answer (score 2):

I will show you how to parse Java-encoded data. However, since I cannot understand the format of the file, the response will not be complete:

First, load the file:

```
// load the file
let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/sulthan/Downloads/MN.dat")
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
```

Second, create a simple Java data reader:

```
// create a simple data reader
class Reader {
    let data: Data
    private var offset = 0

    init(data: Data) {
        self.data = data
    }

    var hasMoreData: Bool {
        return offset < data.count
    }

    func skip(length: Int) {
        offset += length
    }

    func readByte() -> UInt8 {
        defer { offset += 1}
        return data[offset]
    }

    // java bytes are unsigned
    func readJavaByte() -> Int8 {
        return Int8(bitPattern: readByte())
    }

    func readBytes(length: Int) -> Data {
        defer { offset += length }
        return data.subdata(in: offset ..< offset + length)
    }

    private func readJavaUShort() -> UInt16 {
        let byte1 = UInt16(exactly: readByte())!
        let byte2 = UInt16(exactly: readByte())!

        return (byte1 << 8) | byte2
    }

    func readJavaShort() -> Int16 {
        return Int16(bitPattern: readJavaUShort())
    }

    // Java UTF-8 encodes the length as first two bytes (unsigned java short)
    func readJavaUtf() -> String? {
        let length = readJavaUShort()
        let data = readBytes(length: Int(length))
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }

    private func readUInt32() -> UInt32 {
        let short1 = UInt32(exactly: readJavaUShort())!
        let short2 = UInt32(exactly: readJavaUShort())!

        return (short1 << 16) | short2
    }

    func readJavaInt() -> Int32 {
        let short1 = Int32(exactly: readJavaShort())!
        let short2 = Int32(exactly: readJavaShort())!

        return (short1 << 16) | short2
    }

    // interpret the 4 bytes as a floating point number
    func readJavaFloat() -> Float {
        let bits = readUInt32()
        return Float(bitPattern: bits)
    }
}
```

Third, parse the data. I cannot do this completely since the data format is unknown:

```
// create a reader from our data
let reader = Reader(data: data)

// some data I don't understand
reader.skip(length: 4)

var offset = 0
while reader.hasMoreData {
    // some data I don't understand in the beginning and after every 52 items
    if offset % 53 == 0 {
        reader.skip(length: 5)
    }

    print(reader.readJavaUtf())
    print(reader.readJavaFloat())
    print(reader.readJavaFloat())

    offset += 1
}
```

The data parsing will crash with the provided data after some items are parsed. I am assuming you know how to handle that since you know the format.

Comment: The name of the State is saved as a String UTF8, next the latitude and longitude as a Float, is that what u meant by format of file ?

Comment: @yerpy Yes, but there are **other** data, e.g. I am pretty sure the first byte is the number of items and there are 8 other bytes which probably have some meaning too. You cannot parse the data without understanding the format.

Comment: Could you link the crash description ? I am trying to get more infromation about data format from the guy who made it

Comment: @yerpy It crashes because there are 5 additional bytes between "Ham Lake" and "Hastings". The bytes are "00 04 00 7F FA". It's possible the file got corrupted somehow.

Comment: @yerpy Updated the code so that will actually parse the entire file but it's a bit random.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the answer is accepted. If I'll get more informations then i'll post a comment with what you could change in the answer